# Unable to use Vector from System.Windows in IronPython

Tags: ironpython

I'm running into problems when I try to use the Vector class in IronPython.  I think I may be missing a simple step.

I'm using IronPython version 2.7.3 with Python Tools for Visual Studio.  My code looks like this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows")
import System.Windows

x = System.Windows.Vector(4, 5)
```

When I run this I get an exception:

```
MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code:  attribute 'Vector' of 'namespace#' object is read-only
```

Any ideas of what I am missing?  It's been a while since I last used IronPython, so I'm hoping is a really silly mistake.

Comment: I should also note I don't have any problems with importing System and then using Console to write out things to the prompt, so this is really weird.  Not sure why their different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heh, I figured it out.

I needed to include the following line:

```
clr.AddReference("WindowsBase")
```

Now it's functioning as expected :)